# Android Recyclerview scroll to specific position

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, scroll, auto

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r89eQ.jpg)

How can I achieve  this on android  Java in the alert dialog I have  category  recyclerview  and in activity  I have  nested recyclerview of category  and products  i want  to scroll  to specific category  on click of the dialog recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Three steps :

- Find the position of the selected category.
- get its x, y position depending on vscroll or hscroll
- Added NestedScrollView encapsulating RecyclerView and set its position with the help of scrollTo or smoothScrollTo method of nestedScrollView.